# How to create a setup(.exe) file for my web apllication which uses mysql, java7 and runs on tomcat7

Tags: java, mysql, windows-installer, tomcat7, inno-setup

I have created a simple web application (the simplest possible) to connect to a mySQL data base and in jsp page trying to say that the data base is connected.
The primary task is now to make it a single executable file(.exe file).
1. That is if I install the Software it should install the java of of the specific version(silently).
2. It should install mysql of the specific version(silently).
3. And at the end if I hit the specified url of software it should show the jsp page on the browser.
I have tried inno-setup and advanced installer but not able to understand how to achieve the current scenario.

This is inno-setup file which i tried

`````
AppName=MyApp
AppVersion=1.0
AppPublisher=Gopal
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyApp
DefaultGroupName=MyApp
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=output  
; "ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64" requests that the install be
; done in "64-bit mode" on x64, meaning it should use the native
; 64-bit Program Files directory and the 64-bit view of the registry.
; On all other architectures it will install in "32-bit mode".
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
; Note: We don't set ProcessorsAllowed because we want this
; installation to run on all architectures (including Itanium,
; since it's capable of running 32-bit code too). ````

[Files]             
; Install x64 if running in 64-bit mode (x64; see above), x86.exe otherwise.   
Source: "apache-tomcat-7.0.100\*.*"; DestDir: "{app}\tomcat"; Check: Is64BitInstallMode; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "apache-tomcat-7.0.100\bin\startup.bat"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "start.bat"; 
Source: "apache-tomcat-7.0.100\bin\shutdown.bat"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "stop.bat"; 

[Run]     
Filename: "{app}\tomcat\bin\service.bat"; Parameters: "install"   
Filename: "{app}\start.bat"; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{cm:AppName}}; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent

[UninstallRun]   
; uninstall mysql and tomcat as services  
;Filename: "{app}\stop.bat";
;Filename: "{app}\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"; Parameters: "--remove MyApp_MySQL" 
;Filename: "set"; Parameters: "CATALINA_HOME={app}\tomcat"
;Filename: "{app}\tomcat\bin\tomcat6.exe"; Parameters: "//DS//MyApp_Tomcat"

[CustomMessages]
AppName=MyApp
LaunchProgram=Start MyApp after finishing installation
`````

But still its not starting. ANy issues any one can see ?

[image: The image for log file]

Comment: What's the use case behind this?

Comment: I am just trying to build a demo software as of now to have a idea how its going to work and later i have another real time time app for which i need to create installer for.

Comment: containers maybe. or a small VM. A realtime app is a bit of a different case.

Comment: the first issue i am facing to make this sample app into a installer later i can check with the real time app.

Comment: Not able to update the entire log file sir. So only written still not starting. @MartinPrikryl